# Modifying spring data repository methods (mongo)

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, soft-delete

I have the following classes: MyEntity, MyEntityRepository, MyEntityCustomRepository, MyEntityCustomRepositoryImpl.

MyEntity:

```
@Document
class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private final String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Boolean isDeleted = false;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Instant deletedAt;
}
```

MyEntityRepository:

```
@Repository
interface MyEntityRepository extends MongoRepository<MyEntity, ObjectId>, MyEntityCustomRepository {}
```

MyEntityCustomRepository:

```
 public interface MyEntityCustomRepository {

     List <MyEntity> someCustomMethod(Set<ObjectId> ids);

 }
```

MyEntityCustomRepositoryImpl

```
class MyEntityCustomRepositoryImpl implements MyEntityCustomRepository {

    private final MongoTemplate template;

    MyEntityCustomRepositoryImpl(MongoTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @Override
    public List <MyEntity> someCustomMethod(Set<ObjectId> ids) {
        Query query = new Query()
        ...
        return template.find(query, MyEntity.class);
    }
}
```

Now I want to modify all find/get/count etc methods in the MyEntityRepository by adding  param `Criteria.where("isDeleted).is(false)` to all queries.

It's easy to add this query param to my custom method, but what will be the best way to override methods from the CrudRepository extended by the MyEntityRepository?

Comment: You can use `@Subselect` to refine your table which can be used by you repository. Refer https://medium.com/@jonathan.turnock/exposing-subset-view-of-the-database-with-a-jpa-repository-over-rest-5b9d6e07344b

Comment: @akash not sure if this is the best way to handle this. 
1. I am not using the Hibernate
2. Does Subselect work with nosql documents?
3. For sure in future I'll need to implement methods like findDeletedById that require search by where("isDeleted).is(true)